# How to refresh Gitlab Webinterface

Tags: git, refresh, gitlab

When I optimize my git repository via shell (git gc --aggressive), the new size of the repository is not shown by gitlab.

How can I refresh the shown repo size in Gitlab?

Comment: Do you do your `gc` on your local cloned repo, or on the repo on the GitLab server side?

Comment: on Gitlab server side

Comment: So in the bare repo managed by gitlab, then. Did you try a sequence similar to http://stevelorek.com/how-to-shrink-a-git-repository.html? `rm -rf .git/refs/original/
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all
$ git gc --prune=now
$ git gc --aggressive --prune=now`

Comment: I have only used git gc --agressive --prune=now

Comment: What happen if you stop/restart your GitLab server? Does it refresh the size then?

Comment: no. That I have already tested. Sorry I had forgotten to mention this...

Answer (score 2):

After every push to repo Gitlab reset cached data:

```
  def expire_cache
    Rails.cache.delete(cache_key(:size))
    Rails.cache.delete(cache_key(:branch_names))
    Rails.cache.delete(cache_key(:tag_names))
    Rails.cache.delete(cache_key(:commit_count))
    Rails.cache.delete(cache_key(:graph_log))
  end
```

As you can see - repo size in cache.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `git gc --aggressive --prune=now` on the server (within the git repo in question), and again on your local cloned repo. Then on your local clone repo make a real or erroneous commit, and push the change `git push`. Check the size of the repo on gitlab and see if it is correct now. This has fixed gitlabs web reported size for me in the past, after removing large tars from repos. But i never actually debuged why...

Comment: Make sure both your local repo and server repo are the same before trying. Maybe just rm your local repo and clone into it, just to be sure.

Comment: Also [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19596157/2083509) is probably why you need to make a push.